# Laravel + Angular: Securing Angular Pages

Tags: css, angularjs, .htaccess, laravel, authentication

How do I prevent users not-logged into Laravel session from downloading AngularJS pages?

I have a website with Laravel on the back-end. There is also an AngularJS application which is placed in the folder public/myApp/index.html. .htaccess returns any files referenced so http://www.example.com/myApp/index.html returns the Angular application and all requests for js and css are downloaded without authentication.

What is the best way to prevent the download of all js, html, and css files related to my Angular app (i.e. in the /myApp subdirectories) for all users *not* authenticated into Larvel session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these options really resolved what I was looking for. What I ended up doing was the following. I am using a 3rd party Angular front-end template (Angular from ThemeForest) with hundreds of thousands of lines of code and hundreds of different files. A large portion of those files are stylesheets and generic JavaScript libraries (Angular, JQuery, etc.) I don't mind putting that content into the public folder and serving the files to non-authenticated users.

But, the other portion of my files are the modified files. For example, one file has navigation elements that pretty much layout the entire format of my proprietary business system and say a lot about the internal operations of the business. So, something as simple as the navigation html, css, and js is sensitive and should only be served to authenticated users.

What I did was split the public and protected content into identical (or at least similar) directory trees with one located at /public/* and the other located at /storage/app/*. All my non-sensitive content (mostly the template stylesheets and generic JS libraries) goes in the "public" tree while the sensitive content goes in my "storage/app" tree. So for example:

`- public
--- js
----- someThirdPartyJavaScript.js
----- loginController.js (unprotected)
----- ...
--- libs
----- angular.js
----- jquery.js
----- ...
--- css
----- unprotectedStyleSheet.css
----- ...
--- tpl
----- loginTemplate.html
- storage (all protected content goes in this tree)
--- app
----- js
------- myApp.js
------- directives
--------- myCustomDirective.js
--------- businessNavigationDirective.js (sensitive and proprietary)
----- css (for protected css files)
----- libs (for protected libs)
----- tpl (for protected .html files)
------- clientInformationSheet.html (sensitive content indicating the structure of our customer data)`

In .htaccess, I used the following rule to basically return any file that exists in the public tree:

```
    # If the file exists in laravel/public and the URI does not specify ".php" then go get it.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/laravel/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess sends all other requests to be handled by Laravel index.php

Then, I created a Laravel 5.2 route to catch all for routes within my Angular app. Notice that the middleware specifies auth so these files will not be return to the user from the storage directory unless the user has authenticated:

```
use League\Flysystem\Util\MimeType as MimeType;

Route::any('/{any}', ['middleware' => 'auth', function($uri){
    // Auth::logout();
    $uri = storage_path('app/' . $uri);

    if (!File::exists($uri)){
        return "Path not found.";
    } 

    $extension = File::extension($uri);

    if (array_key_exists($extension, MimeType::getExtensionToMimeTypeMap())){
        $mimeType = MimeType::getExtensionToMimeTypeMap()[$extension];  
    } else {
        $mimeType = "text/plain";
    }

    return response(File::get($uri))
        ->header('Content-Type', $mimeType);

}])->where('any', '^MySuperCoolApplicationSubDirectory/.*');
```

Keeping directory structures pretty similar between "public" and "storage/app" made it really easy to organize which files are sensitive and which are not and the application continued to function as it had before, this time with all sensitive content being blocked from unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 1):

I have often come across this problem and have found a solution that is easy to implement and completely secure.

You can define a route for loading all the 'SECURE' templates through angularJs in Laravel like so :

```
Route::get('/templates/secured/{name}', function ($name) {
  if(Auth::check())
    return view('templates.' . $name);
  else
    return '404';
});
```

If you really must serve your static files after auth. 
Here is a small hack....
You can write your static JS and CSS code inside .php files and store them inside 'templates/assets/'

You can then use the same approach as mentioned above.
You won't be compromising much speed either. And all your syntax coloring and indentations for css and js will work inside the php files.

Comment: This is close, but I'm not returning a blade template located in /templates. I would need Laravel to return the file located at public/myApp/css/style.css, for example. Similar files exist for js, html, and other files. Can I use return File("public/{...}") or something? I think that returns a download request to the browser. But, will that work?

Comment: By default, everything in the public folder is publicly available to anyone with the absolute path to that file.

Their paths have higher priority than Laravel Routes.

For authenticating the static files, you would have to serve them through php which is a very bad practice and is slow as shit.

I wouldn't recommend it. Moreover, your JS and CSS files are meant to be public. If you are needing to protect them then maybe there is something wrong with your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass jwt(json web token) between client and server. If user is logged in jwt will be stored so even before you have to send API request to laravel back-end, angular can detect not authed user by not having jwt payload. I use [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for handling jwt from laravel and 
[satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for angular to handle user auth and storing jwt token passed from laravel.