# Authentication in laravel + angularjs Best Practices

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, laravel-5

I am building an application which has a laravel back-end and an angular front-end.
The question is how to route. This is a very common question but i have so far not able to get any comprehensive answer to it.
1 option is to use laravel only as an api and use angular for all routings including authentication. This is not a very good approach.
2nd is to make everything a laravel view. this is very secure but sort of looses the purpose of angular. 
([similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716982/laravel-angular-securing-angular-pages))

3rd option which i am keen on using is to make 2 view in laravel 1 for all (including guests) and another for authenticated areas. These two will be like 2 single page angular applications all the routes inside the application would be angular. This makes sure that only authenticated users have access to the 2nd page but the view are all anyways accessible only through the application.

any suggestion or changes?

Comment: Why isn't the first option considered good? In order to utilize angular it makes sense to have it as a stand alone app that speaks to an api. If you don't want/need the full fledged framework that angular provides then perhaps you would be better off with piecing together what you actually need (ie react)

Comment: @JimL The only reason why i don't want to use the first option is because of the added security feature that laravel offers. I'll have to implement the entire authentication functionality in Angular also and it can be quite error prone.

Comment: Anyway, you will authenticate users in back-end, which is Laravel. In Angular part, you will only play like a client and you basically can not do anything to make back-end insecure. I usually use option 3, but I implement it outside Laravel, that is no view in Laravel. Just simple HTML pages for Angular. The insecurity comes when you have to implement authentication on back-end yourself, because Laravel does not provide a simple-to-use token-based authentication. If you do that, take care a lot. Read more about it and use JWT at last :)

Comment: But anyway, you have to do authorization on Angular part too. That makes things a bit harder, but there are already made packages that do pretty good.